# Cgridview generate pager bad link

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I have a problem with Yii cgridview.. It was work properly, but I don't know when it becomes error.. When I checked with inspect element, I found that the pager is generate a bad link for the page link. That's why the web will error when I click the next button.

The cgridview generate this bad link:

```
<a href="/gso/admin/userContact/index/admin%2FuserContact%2Findex//UserContact_page/2">2</a>
```

It must be:

```
<a href="/gso/admin/userContact/index/UserContact_page/2">2</a>
```

Why it can happen? They duplicate some url and made it error :(..

Please help me.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

For me it is hard to find out the problem with the information you gave.

But, Yii allows you define a route which will resemble in pagination link. ie,

```
    'route'=>'YourController/Method'
```

Code will come as

```
    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Controller',
                    array
                    (
                        'pagination' => array
                        (
                           'pageSize' => 10,
                           'route'=>'YourController/Method' //This is your custom route 
                        ), 

                    )                
    );
    $this->render('index', array(
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,            
    ));
```

May be (My guessing) you have write your route as

```
   'route'=>'userContact/index'
```

Check this link for more http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination#route-detail

Answer (score 0):

I think Yii's CPagination class has some bugs. Depending on your routes setup, it will append the $_GET array with your current path like /userContact/index. CPagination in-turn passes these $_GET variables as params in $this->createUrl($route, $params) resulting in a malformed url.

A workaround is to unset that $_GET variable before calling the pager widget like this:

```
unset( $_GET[Yii::app()->request->url] );
$this->widget('CLinkPager', array('pages'=>$pager));
```

I usually have a path setup like `http://example.com/file/index?page=1` (which is path format to controller/action but $_GET vars appended) so I just `unset($_GET['/file/index'])` which works for me.